# React native: invariant violation when using react-navigation, react-navigation-tabs & react-navigation-stack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am creating a simple mobile app, and trying to set up the navigation.
Here is how I added the packages:

```
npm install @react-navigation/bottom-tabs
npm install react-navigation
npm install react-navigation-tabs
npm install react-navigation-stack
```

when package.json got updated I got this error:
invariant violation: 'main" has not been registered. this happens if Metro is run from the wrong folder.
before adding these packages the app was functioning well (it is only 2 components for now).
any thoughts?[enter image description here][2]

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AakPR.jpg)

Comment: Are you run pod install?

Comment: remove node_modules folder then use npm install and run the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kill the metro bundler, and run react-native run-android again.

Comment: this works for now thank you, but I need to test the app on my phone and I use expo. any suggestions?

Comment: Never mind. It turned out I used an older version of the navigation packages, expo no longer recognize them. 
just deleted older packages and installed @react-navigation/native && react-navigation/bottom-tabs